# Get a vector from a UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to get a `vector` from a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, about the axes of the screen in `Portrait Orientation`. I know I can get the velocity, which is half of the battle, but I'd ideally like a means of getting an angle (compass degrees or radians) about the vertical axis of the screen. For example, a drag from lower-left to upper-right would be a 45 degree angle, top to bottom would be 180 degrees, or bottom to top would be 0 (or 360).

Is this possible? It doesn't have a direction property and the explanation of translation in the docs is a little confusing. Would I need to create a center point manually (about the center of my view), and compare the start/end points of the `Pan Touch` to that? I'm a little unsure of the math needed.

Thanks in advance! ^_^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can get the velocity with :

```
CGPoint velocity = [recognizer velocityInView:self.view]
```

then you can calculate the angle with respect to the x-axis with:

```
float x = velocity.x;
float y = velocity.y;

double angle = atan2(y, x) * 180.0f / 3.14159f;
if (angle < 0) angle += 360.0f;
```

Comment: Could you explain how this code works? I'm not too sure what it's doing.

Comment: It seems that this code works, but that 0 degrees is the horizontal axis (so if I swipe left to right, I get 0 degrees). Can I change that so that top to bottom is 0 degrees?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint startLocation = [sender locationInView:self.view];
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
     startLocation = [sender locationInView:self.view];
}
else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
     CGPoint stopLocation = [sender locationInView:self.view];
     CGFloat dx = stopLocation.x - startLocation.x;
     CGFloat dy = stopLocation.y - startLocation.y;

     double angle = atan2(dy, dx) * 180.0f / M_PI;
     if (angle < 0) angle += 360.0f;
     NSLog(@"angle: %f",angle);
}
```